# Nix how can I reference a username from users.extraUsers?

Tags: nix, nixos

I'd like to reference a user in some nix expression. However rather than just setting it to a string value like `bob` I want to reference a user that is already defined in `users.extraUsers` so I assume something like `users.extraUsers.bob.userName`. Is this possible?

The reason for this, is it gives me some extra static guarentee that I'm referencing a user that will exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make sure a user is defined by looking them up.

```
$ nix repl '<nixpkgs/nixos>'
Welcome to Nix version 2.3.4. Type :? for help.

Loading '<nixpkgs/nixos>'...
Added 6 variables.

nix-repl> config.users.users.${"root"}.name 
"root"

nix-repl> user = "bob"
      
nix-repl> config.users.users.${user}.name
error: attribute 'bob' missing, at (string):1:1

nix-repl> config.users.users.${user}.name or builtins.throw "You referenced a user `${user}' which was not defined."
error: You referenced a user `bob' which was not defined.
```

Note that `extraUsers` is just an alias for `users`.

It's not static in the sense that Nix doesn't static checking beyond limited scope checking, but I hope it helps.